# How to have a single horizontal row of items in a collection view when items have dynamic sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, flowlayout

I am trying to pull an unknown number of Lists from a server, and I have a collection view that has a cell/item for each List. Each cell has a label that has the List's name in it. Since I do not know how long the label will be, I made the cell dynamic size and set the following properties on my UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 11
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 12
```

The sizing of the cell itself is fine, I used auto layout on the label so the cell goes based on the intrinsic size. But my problem is that I either get more than one row of items, or I get a single row that scrolls far beyond my items until there is empty space at the right side. I get these two results when I change the value for `minimumInteritemSpacing`. Is there a better approach?

All I want to do is have a dynamic number of "buttons" or cells (based on # of Lists pulled) and dynamic width (based on List name) and scroll horizontally in a single row.
Each cell with the List's name is going to act like a button that updates several fields with the List's properties when selected.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is make the collection view's cell width the size of the collection view. This would give you a vertical scrolling column (or use a `UITableView`). Each collection view cell would then contain a `UIScrollview` where you can add your content (i.e. the label). This would give you the horizontal scrolling based on the list name.

Comment: Got a screenshot of what you need? Not sure exactly what you want but it sounds like you need a table view for the rows and a horizontal collection in each row for the items.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to implement the size of each cell.